# 11Khz IR receiver

Tags: infrared

I would like to make a receiver for this controller
http://hardware.segakore.fr/en/controller_18.html

I placed the controller in front of a photodiode, and it seems that the carrier is 11KHz instead of the classic 38.
I cannot therefore use a TSOP382.
Is there any other receiver / custom built IR receiver circuit I could build ?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Analog filtering is certainly a possibility, but given the nature of the controller you may well be the result to a microcontroller anyway, so finding one with an ADC that you could use to sample the IR detector and then filter in software might be reasonable, provided that you don't need extremely low power operation.

Comment: Thank you. What do you suggest for the analog part? A photodiode with an operational amplifier? a phototransistor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 11Khz information was wrong. I found it is a 455Khz one. Suitable receivers are the TSOP5700 or TSOP7000 for anyone who may be interested.